# add single static dns record

Tags: server, samba, dns, dhcp

We have a DHCP server for our guests. On that server there is also a share mounted for the guests. The DHCP server has a scope which is out of the range of our domain and is not routable. The DNS is configured to 8.8.8.8.  We want to set a dns record for the share, so we can access the server by the name of the share rather than by the ip.

When the guests type `\\guest-share` it will eventually get there, but it simply takes too long. When they type in the IP address it's opening instantly. I guess that by name it resolves using netbios (configured in Samba)

Has anyone any idea of its possible to keep the DNS pointed at 8.8.8.8 and add the dns record for our guest-share somewhere?

Comment: What is supplying the DHCP?  A server running Ubuntu?  A third party router like Linksys?  There are ways of having different DNS servers setup on a DHCP server.  Best way is to have the DNS sent to the guests as the IP to the DHCP server, then the DHCP server then goes to the 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 Google DNS servers.

Comment: The DHCP is supplied by the same server as the host of the share, a ubuntu machine

Comment: Unfortunately, right now I cannot go deep into this configuration as I don't have a lot of time at the moment.  But, you can look into supplying the guests with the DNS IP of your server through the [dhcp configuration](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/isc-dhcp-server).  Then making sure that your [DNS Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/dns.html) is also configured properly for forwarding to the 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 Google DNS servers.

Comment: If your DHCP server can see the `guest-share` without using the IP address, that means that your guest people would need to have their DNS nameserver go to your DHCP instead of 8.8.8.8 as that is what is causing the slow down is that DNS is looking at 8.8.8.8 first before looking at your local.

Comment: You can install `dnsmasq` as a local resolver (and configure DHCP to announce it to your client) as then you can configure it to use a forwarder except for some specific names for which you can hardcode their resolution locally.